# MySQL 5.5 Create event gives syntax error

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

I have a problem creating EVENT.

I have an 'articoli' table. There is a articoli.titolo field varchar (255) and when I try to create the event like this:

```
CREATE EVENT inser_value
ON SCHEDULE every 1 day
DO INSERT INTO articoli (titolo) VALUES ('my_value');
```

This is the mysqlerror's output

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use n ear 'EVENT inser_value ON SCHEDULE every 1 day DO
>   INSERT INTO articoli (titolo) VALUE' at line 1

Comment: i edit the question. now it's posted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error appears if your MySQL version doesn't support the Event module, or if it's not started.

Please check those two.

This article talks about [How to Configure MySQL Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html).

**Starting MySQL’s Event Scheduler**

MySQL events are executed by a special event scheduler thread. It’s disabled by default so use the following MySQL command can determine whether it’s running:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

If the scheduler is running, at least two rows will be shown and one will have its user field set to `event_scheduler`. If only one row is returned, the scheduler is disabled and events will not run.

You can ensure the scheduler starts when MySQL is launched with the command-line option `--event-scheduler=ON` or `setting event_scheduler=ON` in your MySQL configuration file (my.cnf or my.ini on Windows).

Alternatively, you can start the scheduler from the MySQL command line:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

---

Comment: thank you. i try with SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
But it will put out:
ERROR 1193(HY000): unknow system variable 'event_scheduler'

Comment: Im getting the same error. Check if your mysql version is bigger than 5.1.6  that is when they added event_scheduler functionality.